# Prevent Client DOM XSS Vulnerability in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xss

I am working with Checkmarx to scan my code for any potential vulnerabilities. I am getting

*This untrusted data is embedded straight into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the output.* message with following code.

```
var currentUrl = location.href;
```

I have tried to resolve this with following code, but seems like Checkmarx is not able to detect that I am already sanitizing the data.

```
var currentUrl = checkUrlForXSS(location.href);

// function definition

function checkUrlForXSS(url) {
    const reg = /(script|\)|\(|\>|\<)/ig;
    return url.replace(reg, "");
}
```

Is there any way I can sanitize the data in Javascript and resolve the vulnerability without using any libraries (like DOMPurify)?

Thank you.

Comment: i would say https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

Comment: What are you doing with currentUrl? Could be just a wild goose chase depending on how you use it.

Comment: @TheWuif your suggestion worked! Thank you.

Comment: @epascarello I understand it's a bad practice, will change it in future.